# Space Between Elements in BoxLayout(or any other Layout) LWUIT

Tags: lwuit

I'm having problems removing all spaces and gaps between placed elements in the BoxLayout in LWUIT, i tried

```
    Container toolbar = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS)); 
    toolbar.getStyle().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    toolbar.getStyle().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

with no luck, there is always a small gap between placed elements. How can I do this?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: I would like to see some screenshots

Answer (score 2):

You need to zero out the margin for the elements themselves.

You should also zero the margin for all styles (unselected, selected, pressed, disabled) and not just the current style.